# How to check BullMQ queue size?

Tags: node.js, bullmq

I have a BullMQ dynamic queue.
Is there a way to check how many items there in queue?
I already checked in google & stackoverflow and cannot find any solution.

Comment: https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq/blob/master/docs/gitbook/api/bullmq.queuegetters.md There we go they have some documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a better way of doing it, but something like this may work for you:

```
Queue#getJobs(['waiting', 'active', 'completed', 'failed', 'delayed', 'paused'], 0, 0, false) // meaning asc: false = descending
```

And check the id for each type of job from the results, sort those descending, and grab the first result.

If you found a better way, please post it.